The correct formula for the cosine integral of $(1/x^n)cos^m(ax)$
I am not a math major, just a math and physics hobbyist so pardon me if this sounds easy.
I cannot seem to find an exact source to get the answer, even when I asked perplexity, an AI search engine and it gave me
$$\int \frac{\cos^m(ax)}{x^n}dx = \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{\sin(ax)}{x^{n-1}}\right)\cos^{m-1}(ax) + \frac{m-1}{n} \int \frac{\cos^{m-2}(ax)}{x^{n-1}}dx$$
And it gave me that without citing an exact source although it said it got it from here but I cannot seem to find that exact expression in the website.
Perplexity said

This formula is derived using integration by parts and is detailed in the Wolfram MathWorld article on the Cosine Integral

My question is, that that formula correct? If not, then what is the correct formula as I want to solve
$$\int \frac{\cos^m(ax)}{x^n}dx$$
Where $n, m$ are positive integers.
I want to ask the experts here instead of trusting AI.

What does integration by parts produce for you?

I'll just point out that, in the end, you'll get down to $\int{\cos x\over x},dx$, and that integral can't be expressed in terms of more familiar functions.

@Aruralreader It seems to give me a different answer? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+by+parts+cos%5Em%28ax%29%2Fx%5En+dx

I think the formula that AI gave you is nonsense, as is most of what AI says when asked any serious mathematical question. One way to show it is nonsense: take the simple case, $m=n=2$, $a=1$, and differentiate both sides. You get $${\cos^2x\over x^2}-{1\over2x}={1\over2}{d\over dx}{\sin x\cos x\over x}$$ and it's not hard at all to show that's not right. Please, don't use AI  for math problems. And remember: you can always check any integration formula by differentiating.

@GerryMyerson I thought so as it didn't give a proper citation of where it got it from. Thankfully I asked here to find out.
